# Add a vertical line in tabularx{}

Tags: tabularx, xtable

I have a table like below which works without any error in my main.tex. I would like to add to a vertical line and maybe need some touch about the lines. Many thanks in advance.[image: my table]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \footnotesize
        %\scriptsize
        \centering 
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{R*{6}{C}}
            %\begin{tabular}{ccc|cccc}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Access} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Type} \\
            \cline{2-7} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7} 
            \toprule
            & 0 & 1 & Formal & Informal & Both & No Loan \\ 
            %\midrule
            \cline{2-7} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7}  \\ %\midrule
            HR \textit{\text{(Urban = 1)}} & 18.72\% & 81.28\% &  &  &  & \\
            Education \textit{\text{(Above highschool = 1)}}  & 94.99\% & 5.01\% &  &  &  & \\
            CCP/no.CCP \textit{\text{(CCP= 1)}}  & 90.22\% & 9.78\%  &  &  &  & \\
            Gender \textit{\text{(Male = 1)}}   &  17.33\% & 82.67 &  &  &  & \\
            \bottomrule
            %\end{tabular}
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Chi test} 
        \label{tab:Chi.test}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Vertical lines should not be used with the `booktabs` rules and in your out commented example using `ccc|ccc` the `|` will contain holes. This is by design. Generally vertical lines does not help with the understanding of a data table. You can try `*{2}{C} | *{4}{C}` but it will look bad. I normally emulate lines by adding space between certain columns

Comment: How did you define the  `R` and `C` column types?

Answer (score 1):

Hope the combination of `framed` and `float` will help you to meet the requirement, here is the `MWE`

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{float,framed}
    
    \begin{document}
\begin{leftbar}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \footnotesize
        %\scriptsize
        \centering 
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{r*{6}{c}}
            %\begin{tabular}{ccc|cccc}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Access} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Type} \\
            \cline{2-7} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7} 
            \toprule
            & 0 & 1 & Formal & Informal & Both & No Loan \\ 
            %\midrule
            \cline{2-7} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7}  \\ %\midrule
            HR \textit{\text{(Urban = 1)}} & 18.72\% & 81.28\% &  &  &  & \\
            Education \textit{\text{(Above highschool = 1)}}  & 94.99\% & 5.01\% &  &  &  & \\
            CCP/no.CCP \textit{\text{(CCP= 1)}}  & 90.22\% & 9.78\%  &  &  &  & \\
            Gender \textit{\text{(Male = 1)}}   &  17.33\% & 82.67 &  &  &  & \\
            \bottomrule
            %\end{tabular}
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Chi test} 
        \label{tab:Chi.test}
    \end{table}
\end{leftbar}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: hello thank you very much for the response, but could you click on the photo that I  posted *{2}{C} | *{4}{C} works fine but it is an interrupted line I would like to insert a constant line between 1 and Formal.